# How can I change path for xml2-config

Tags: centos5, php5, environment-variables, configuration, libraries

I've already asked same question in stackoverflow.I need some more help.

I’m trying to upgrade `libxml2` from `2.6.26` to `2.7.7` on `CentOS5.5`

I installed `libxml2-2.7.7` in `/opt/libxml2-2.7.7/bin/`

I'd already installed `2.6.26` in `/usr` by `yum install libxml2 libxml2-devel`.

When I configur PHP5.3 `--with-libxml-dir=/opt/libxml2-2.7.7/bin` message shows.

```
checking whether to enable LIBXML support... yes
checking libxml2 install dir... /opt/libxml2-2.7.7/bin
checking for xml2-config path... /usr/bin/xml2-config
```

PHP’s configure can’ t find `xml2-config` file in `/opt/libxml2-2.7.7/bin`

I don’t want PHP configure looks `/usr/bin/xml2-config` so that installed PHP use `libxml2-2.6.26`.

So,I have two different version of libxml2 NOW

```
#/opt/libxml2-2.7.7/bin/xml2-config --version
2.7.7

# /usr/bin/xml2-config --version
2.6.26
```

And this is PATH environment variable.

```
PATH=/opt/php-5.3.14/bin:/opt/apache-httpd-2.2.22/bin:/opt/libxml2-2.7.7/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/bin
```

I think `/opt/libxml2-2.7.7/bin` is prior to `/usr/bin`.

But if I type `xml2-conifg` without path it is one under `/usr/bin`.

```
# xml2-config --version

2.6.26
```

Is there another settings to make `xml2-config` work under `/opt/libxml2-2.7.7/bin`?

I also changed symbolic　link .

```
ls -la|grep libxml
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2071024 Mar  5 16:56 libxml2.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       39 Apr  4 11:47 libxml2.so -> /opt/libxml2-2.7.7/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.7
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       39 Apr  4 18:59 libxml2.so.2 -> /opt/libxml2-2.7.7/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1298872 Mar  5 16:56 libxml2.so.2.6.26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to configure PHP with `--with-libxml-dir=/opt/libxml2-2.7.7`.
The `/bin` suffix will be added automatically.
See [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/libxml.installation.php). It contains a vague description, but I verified it in the `configure` script:

> The location ([DIR]) specified with --with-libxml-dir ([DIR]=/bin/xml2-config)

Comment: I tried and message was 
`checking libxml2 install dir... /opt/libxml2-2.7.7
checking for xml2-config path... /opt/libxml2-2.7.7/bin/xml2-config`
I HAVE TO 
 `--with-libxml-dir=/opt/libxml2-2.7.7`
DON’T SET
 `-with-libxml-dir=/opt/libxml2-2.7.7/bin` Thank you. I understand.